# How can I change a value in a set method depending on a boolean's answer in Java?

Tags: java, boolean

I'm trying to change the VAT rate of an item depending if it's a luxury item or not.

I've tried using an if inside of my set method but it only uses the pre-set value that I gave it.

```
private double vat = 0.08;
```

is my preset value. My get and set methods are:

```
public double getVat() {
    return this.vat;
}

public void setVat(double vat) {
    if(lux=true) {
    this.vat = 0.10;
    }
    
    else if(lux=false) {
    this.vat = vat;
    }
}
```

and the variable `lux` is

```
private boolean lux;
```

Also, this is what my constructor looks like:

```
public ProductTest(String pname, double price, boolean lux) {
    this.pname = pname;
    
    if(price>0) {
    this.price = price;
    }
    else {
    this.price = 0;
    }
    
    this.lux = lux; //If product type is luxury , =true ----- if product type is not luxury, =false
    
}
```

When I create and object and mark the `lux` variable as true or false, VAT takes the value of 0.08.

```
ProductTest p = new ProductTest("apple", 10, true);
System.out.println(p.getVat());
```

Output: `0.08`

```
ProductTest p = new ProductTest("apple", 10, false);
System.out.println(p.getVat());
```

Output: `0.08`

What can I do to overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: `if(lux=true)` should be `if(lux==true)`, with two equals signs.

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of that `else if` immediately after (and that has the same problem) you can use a simple `else`. It's not like a boolean can assume any other value :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca this has not worked, do you know anything else I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the class in action.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'm new around here, I'm not sure my edits are enough but I don't know what else I can explain about the question.

Comment: `this.vat = lux ? 0.10 : vat`

Comment: No, it should not be `if (lux == true)` as well; never check variables that hold boolean values with equality against `true` or `false`, as those variables bear boolean values themselves, and, instead, it's better to do: `if (lux)..`.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri you're right, I wrote that to point out the "typo" without taking the time to propose the right correction (which you thankfully did)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nede to call `setVat` in the constructor to apply the logic

```
public ProductTest(String pname, double price, boolean lux) {
    this.pname = pname;
    this.price = Math.max(0, price);
    this.lux = lux;
    setVat(vat);
}

public void setVat(double vat) {
    if (lux) {
        this.vat = 0.10;
    } else {
        this.vat = vat;
    }
}
```

Could even be shorter with ternary operator

```
public void setVat(double vat) {
    this.vat = lux ? 0.10 : vat;
}
```

---

Or do it differently by putting the logic in the `getVat`

```
public ProductTest(String pname, double price, boolean lux) {
    this.pname = pname;
    this.price = Math.max(0, price);
    this.lux = lux;
}

public double getVat() {
    return lux ? 0.10 : vat;
}

public void setVat(double vat) {
    this.vat = vat;
}
```

Comment: Yep, putting setVat in the constructor worked. But why? If you have the time could you please explain?

Comment: @tohli because a program won't execute instructions you don't tell it to. If you want a method and its code to run you'll have to call it explicitly. Simply setting a value for a property is not equivalent to calling its setter (getters and setters are just a convention, they're not enforced at the language level)

Comment: @tohli if your logic is in `setVat`, do you need to call it to get it executed, or set the logic in the `getVat` , see my edit

Answer (score 1):

You should write your `setVat` method as follows:

```
public void setPrice(double vat) {
        //Setting vat to 0.10 if it's a luxury product
        if (lux) {
            this.vat = 0.10;
        } else {
            //Setting the given vat if it's a consistent value
            if (vat > 0) {
                this.vat = vat;
            }
        }
    }
```

This will ensure both of your logics:

- if the item is a luxury product its vat must be `0.10` regardless of what has been passed
- if vat is a positive consistent value then it can be assigned to the object's field.

Within your method you should check if `lux` is true by simply placing it within the `if` parenthesis. There is no need to check whether lux is equal to true, a boolean value already represents the outcome of a comparison. Besides, as others have pointed out in the comments, to perform a comparison you need to use the `==` operator, not the `=`, the latter represents a value assignment.

Also, you should centralize your vat setting logic as I've shown you above. In your setter method you only checked whether the product is a luxury product or not, without making sure that the given value is consistent. You should include both logics within your setter method, to centralize it and avoid code repetition, and invoke the setter within the constructor. First, assign the product name, its price and the `lux` flag and then set up the vat value by invoking the `setVat` method.

```
public class ProductTest {

    private String pname;
    private double price;
    private double vat = 0.08;
    private boolean lux;

    public ProductTest(String pname, double price, boolean lux) {
        this.pname = pname;
        //Alternatively you could also define a price setter with the following logic and invoke it
        this.price = price > 0 ? price : 0;
        this.lux = lux; //If product type is luxury , =true ----- if product type is not luxury, =false
        setVat(vat);
    }

    public double getVat() {
        return this.vet;
    }

    public void setVat(double vat) {
        if (lux) {
            this.vat = 0.10;
        } else {
            if (vat > 0) {
                this.vat = vat;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s at %g with %g vat is%s luxury", pname, price, vat, lux ? "" : " not");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProductTest pt1 = new ProductTest("test1", 0.50, true);
        System.out.println(pt1);

        ProductTest pt2 = new ProductTest("test2", 0.05, false);
        System.out.println(pt2);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, I think this works but you've written for a set price method, I was looking for the answer for setVat but a few edits and I think it would work for VAT as well. Thanks!

Comment: @tohli I've copied your code and there were both `price` and `vat`. I didn't know if that was a type. In any other case you could simply achieving the same by apllying it to the vat field. I'll update my code.

Comment: @tohli updated the code. We don't call it `vat` here and when I saw your code I thought price and vat names had been swapped as a synonym (representing the same thing). It's more clear now, of course. Hope this code will help you out as a general reference.